# Eigenfunctions spaces

Tags: sobolev-spaces, eigenfunctions

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^N$ with boundary of class $C^2$. 
It is known that there exists a sequence of eigenvalues $0<\lambda_1<\lambda_2\leq\ldots\leq\lambda_j\leq\ldots$ and a sequence of corresponding eigenfunctions $\{\varphi_j\}_{j\in\mathbb{N}^*}$ for Dirichlet problem 
$$-\Delta u=\lambda u,\quad u|_{\partial\Omega}=0$$

How to show that $\varphi_j\in W^{2,p}(\Omega)$, with some $p>N$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know that the solution $u \in H_0^1(\Omega)$ of
$$-\Delta u = f$$
satisfies $u \in W^{2,p}(\Omega)$ for $f \in L^p(\Omega)$. Now, you can take $u = \varphi_j$ and $f = \lambda_j \, \varphi_j$.

Comment: Due to the Sobolev embedding theorem, you get $\varphi_j \in L^q(\Omega)$ for some $q > 2$. If you do not have $q > N$ already, you can iterate these arguments.

Comment: You start with $\varphi_j \in H^2$. By Sobolev embedding, you get $\varphi_j \in L^{q_1}$ with some $q_1 > 2$. From the equation, you get $\varphi_j \in W^{2,q_1}$. Now, Sobolev embedding gives $\varphi_j \in L^{q_2}$ for some $q_2 > q_1$. And so on.